# How to change boolean field values and save to database in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i have difficulty updating boolean values to favorite fields, I want when I click the star the value will change to false and the data will be hidden with changes in the database. I've only been studying for 1 week so I'm still bad, cherish any suggestions!

My code:

```
class Favorite {
  String nodeId;
  String name;
  String type;
  bool favorite;
  int userId;
  String userName;
  int timeCreate;

  static DateTime _fromJson(int int) => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int);
  static int _toJson(DateTime time) => time.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  Favorite({
    this.nodeId,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.favorite,
    this.userId,
    this.userName,
    this.timeCreate
  });

  factory Favorite.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Favorite(
      nodeId: json['nodeId'] as String,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      type: json['type'] as String,
      favorite: json['favorite'] as bool,
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      userName: json['userName'] as String,
      timeCreate: json['timeCreate'] as int
    );
  }
}
Future<List<Favorite>> fetchFavorite() async{
  var requestHeaders = <String, String>{
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ2YW50aHUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjAyMTA4NzcsImV4cCI6MTYyMjgwMjg3N30.9QrtUCQpy-Jd_4b7YwLY6GXlEab4M2_NDLRipNcFF_iEmIIzX1JKlotu7L_WJbXTJgtpFYY9kIW3GY6zhAx-JA"
  };
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL1), headers: requestHeaders);
  print(response);
  print(response.body);
  var decoded = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
  var responseJson = json.decode(decoded);
  return (responseJson['data']['content'] as List)
      .map((p) => Favorite.fromJson(p))
      .toList();
}
Future<Favorite> setFavorite(String nodeId, bool favorite) async{
  var requestHeaders = <String, String>{
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ2YW50aHUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjAyOTAxMDQsImV4cCI6MTYyMjg4MjEwNH0.G7vSN6jU9Y-87qEiU4UeyLZN6JkuRTFnmqkkYLWvIJZ8yCUXFSU8cAbIZ-RxD6-4Pab_9yqTC9Yo5fFpVcpcIQ"
  };
  final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(URL_SETFAVORITE),
    headers: requestHeaders,
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Favorite.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to update album.');
  }
}
```

I have shown my favorites list, now  want to hide the star when changing the favorite value to false

```
SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  child: Padding(

                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 114, top: 7),
                                    child: IconButton(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        icon: isStar
                                            ? Icon(
                                          Icons.star_border_outlined,
                                          size: 25,
                                        )
                                            : Icon(Icons.star,
                                            color: Colors.amber, size: 25),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            // Here we changing the icon.
                                            isStar = !isStar;
                                          });
                                        }),
                                  ))
```

Comment: You mean you want to hide the star completely rather than changing to `border_outlined` star?

Comment: Yep,that's what I mean and at the same time set favorite = false. I already have an API that changes a favorite field based on nodeId but I do not really understand the flow and how to do it

Comment: Then you need to write conditional statement in `Padding` child. Now the conditional statement is inside `IconButton`. You don't need to do that. If `isStart` show `IconButton` else show empty `Container`. You can then make API call on inside button pressed event.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to call api from flutter properly, in my case how to implement it?